# How do you prevent an Android Wear activity from having multiple instances?

Tags: android, wear-os

Sometimes, most of the time when my LG G watch closes the app automatically by going to sleep/dim mode,  if I open the app again by going to the start menu there are two instances of the activity opened (when I slide one off the previous one is underneath).

This never happens in a phone, is this how activities work in Android Wear? Should I "finish()" them in onPause()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the `android:launchMode` attribute in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for the activity?

perhaps `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` will help you out.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: This seems to have done the trick, thanks. One thing to note though is that if you launch the activity from Android studio upon uploading the app and then you close the app and try to open it again this second time you won't be able to open it and the screen will turn black (I'll have to do more testing to find out why this happens before I release my app). My guess is that the ADB launch is somehow different than the standard "start" menu launch.

Comment: Be aware that if youre using an intent to pass the app data, youll need to look into onNewIntent(Intent i)

Comment: I am running into the same problem, very annoying.

Comment: @SoftwareDev It's been a long time, but did you learn anything about why this happens?

Comment: @akodiakson I'm don't remember exactly, but looking at my commit history for the app in github which is titled "Fixed issue that caused activity to open more than once." what I did is added the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to a notify intent I had, this is code I used: `notifyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`  In the same commit I removed `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` from the code, so that must not have been the real solution after all.  Best of luck, and let me you know what you find out because I'd like to remember why that worked.

Comment: @akodiakson I remember a little more now. I think that the notifications were starting new activities and that's why I need to add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag.

Comment: That wouldnt prevent the issue of having multiple activities though, that would in fact do the opposite, unless you had something that was stopping and restarting the activity instance using some other means than launchmode.

Comment: @r2DoesInc I think that's what the notifications were doing and that's why I had to add it. I do remember reading about that somewhere but it was long ago.