# Android Wear Multiple Activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, wear-os

When creating more then one activity in Android Wear (i.e. 2 activities, one showing a list of items, the other showing the item details), Android Wear 1.5.0 with Android Marshmellow 6.0.1 shows separated instances of the app in the system main menu, as many as are the activities, using the activity name. It is also possible to open the activities (e.g 'DetailsActivity') directly from the main menu.
Why is this happening?
Does this behaviour disappear once you create the final apk? 
Is it better to use only one activity and a number of fragments in Android Wear developing?

Comment: What does your AndroidManifest show?

Comment: You're right! the manifest showed the intent filter android.intent.category.LAUNCHER and MAIN for each declared Activity!
Now the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any issue with using multiple activities in an Android app. You may refer with this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310832/how-do-you-prevent-an-android-wear-activity-from-having-multiple-instances). Be noted that if you launch the activity from Android studio upon loading the app and then you close the app and try to open it again the second time, you won't be able to open it and the screen will turn black.